# windows docker, xterm: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) or KillClient on X server

Tags: windows, docker, x11, xserver

I am

**Running GUI app in linux docker container on windows host**
https://dev.to/darksmile92/run-gui-app-in-linux-docker-container-on-windows-host-4kde

Instead using `firefox` as above article used, I use `xterm`. 
however, the problem is that, my `xterm` won't stay long, it will disappear all by itself after a while (mostly around 8 minutes time), with the error:

```
xterm: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) or KillClient on X server "10.66.xx.xx:0.0"

[1]+  Exit 84                 xterm
```

It's not the Xserver's problem, as the `xeyes` that comes with it can stay long, and it wouldn't be the `xterm` problem either, because it can stay on for months in my Linux host. I suspect it has something to do with `docker`.

I've searched everywhere but don't have a clue how to fix the issue. I don't even know how to debug the situation.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix that situation?